# Error handling in pyomo - division by zero

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, divide-by-zero

I am working on a linear optimization problem where I have a set of cities and a set of powerplants. The cities have an electricity demand that needs to be satisfied. However, in the context of my problem, in certain time periods, the cities have no electricity demand (from the power plants because they can produce some of their own). I do not think the specific details are very important so below is my best description of the issue.

The objective function contains the following term:

[Term in objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wReVv.png)

I created the appropriate city and month sets and set up my objective function as:

```
sum(sum(1/model.monthly_demand[c,t]*model.theta[c] for c in model.cities) for t in model.months)
```

The issue clearly arises when `monthly_demand[c,t] = 0` as i get a division by zero error. And I am not sure how to deal with this. Ideally I would like `theta[c]` to be set to zero in that case but I am unsure how to do this. I tried adding some if/else statements in the sum() function but this is not possible as far as I understand.

I think I can also define a function that is passed into the pyomo objective, so my idea was to try something like an if statement that sets `theta[c]` to zero when the monthly demand is zero, but this was not successful.

Another idea was to set the demands to something like 0.000001 but I would like this to be a last resort solution because I think it will cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just make a subset wherever convenient of the non-zero elements of demand.  **I am assuming `demand` is a parameter** which would make sense, but you didn't specify.  Then use that subset as the basis of summation.  This will avoid including the empty/zero elements.

Note the elements of the objective in the printout of the model.

##### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

demand_data = { ('LA', 0) : 20,
                ('LA', 1) : 0,
                ('SF', 1) : 15,
                ('NY', 0) : 20,
                ('NY', 1) : 30}

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('electricity')

m.C = pyo.Set(initialize=['LA', 'SF', 'NY'])
m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(2)))

# VARS
m.x = pyo.Var(m.C, m.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

# PARAMS
m.demand = pyo.Param(m.C, m.T, initialize=demand_data, default=0)

# CONSTRAINTS
# ...

# OBJ
# make a subset of the non-zero demand periods
nonzero_demand_domain = {(c,t) for c in m.C for t in m.T if m.demand[c, t] > 0}

# use that in your objective...
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.x[c, t] for c, t in nonzero_demand_domain))

m.pprint()
```

##### Output:

```
4 Set Declarations
    C : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'LA', 'SF', 'NY'}
    T : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}
    demand_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    C*T :    6 : {('LA', 0), ('LA', 1), ('SF', 0), ('SF', 1), ('NY', 0), ('NY', 1)}
    x_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    C*T :    6 : {('LA', 0), ('LA', 1), ('SF', 0), ('SF', 1), ('NY', 0), ('NY', 1)}

1 Param Declarations
    demand : Size=6, Index=demand_index, Domain=Any, Default=0, Mutable=False
        Key       : Value
        ('LA', 0) :    20
        ('LA', 1) :     0
        ('NY', 0) :    20
        ('NY', 1) :    30
        ('SF', 1) :    15

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=6, Index=x_index
        Key       : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('LA', 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('LA', 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('NY', 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('NY', 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('SF', 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('SF', 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : x[NY,0] + x[NY,1] + x[LA,0] + x[SF,1]

7 Declarations: C T x_index x demand_index demand obj
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer because I am new to the site but I just wanted to say a big thank you for the thorough answer! Very easy to understand and solved my problem :)